# HTML Email - How to achieve spacing between links on same row in ALL email clients

Tags: html, css, email, html-table

On a typical HTML webpage, this would be very easy. For email, not so much.

I'm sure you're all familiar with the challenges of getting email clients to render things consistently. It basically throws divs out the window.

I'm concerned with the About, Practice Areas, etc. links..

Here's what I'd like to achieve
[image]

That's how it renders in a web browser, which is perfect.

But this is what I get in Outlook 2010.
[image]

My problem is.. I need to use text-align:center on the parent element to center everything. But in Outlook 2010, it stacks the children elements vertically instead of lining up in one row.

When I change it so I have just links inside the table (as opposed to nesting tables), I lose all padding on the links.

[No padding on links..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLhb2.jpg)

Is there any way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>|Jan '18|</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            @media(max-width: 500px) {
                .frame {
                    width: 97% !important;
                }
                .fullIMG {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }
                #contentGrid {
                    padding: 10px 20px !important;
                }
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <BODY>

            <!-- Beginning of white background table -->
            <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 550px; background-color: white; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; opacity:.95" class="frame">
            <tr>
            <td>

                    <!-- Pre-Header -->
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center; padding: 0px 20px;">
                        <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 20px"><i>We have collected <strong>MORE THAN $1 BILLION</strong> for thousands of clients.</i></p>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- End of Pre-Header -->

                    <!--  Header Row  -->   
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--  Header Table  -->
                        <table align="center" style="padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="https://www.hupy.com/" target="_blank">
                             <img alt="Voted Best, Rated Vest" style="width: 90%; height: auto; " src="https://image.ibb.co/nai2NG/logo_tight.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End of Header Table -->
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- End of Header Row  --> 

                    <!-- Homebase Links Row -->
                    <tr>
                    <td>

                        <hr align="center" style="width:90%;">

                        <!-- Homebase Links Table -->
                        <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                                <table align="left" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/aboutus.cfm"><strong>About</strong></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table align="left" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px;text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/practice_areas/"><strong>Practice Areas</strong></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table align="left" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/library/"><strong>Legal Info</strong></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table align="left" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/case-results.cfm"><strong>Results</strong></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table align="left" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/contact.cfm"><strong>Contacts</strong></a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End of Homebase Links Table -->

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- End of Homebase Row -->

                        <!-- Snipppet Row -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 0px 20px" align="center">
                                <h2 style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 25px; text-align:left;">CASE RESULT: $1.5 Million for Rider Struck by Inattentive Driver</h2>
                                    <a href="https://www.hupy.com/case_results/-1-5-million-for-rider-struck-by-inattentive-driver.cfm" target="blank"> 
                                        <img class="fullIMG" src="https://image.ibb.co/eNfVbb/1_5mill.jpg" alt="$1.5 Million" style="width: 100%; height: auto; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(165,42,42,.7)">
                                    </a>
                                <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; text-align:left;">In July 2017, our client and his wife were on a casual motorcycle ride in Waukesha County when the driver of a minivan failed to see their motorcycle and turned left in front of them. A terrible crash occurred and both occupants of the motorcycle were ejected. Find out what happened when Hupy and Abraham fought the insurance company to get a $1.5 million settlement.</p>
                            </td>                       
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://www.hupy.com/case_results/-1-5-million-for-rider-struck-by-inattentive-driver.cfm">Click me</a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End of Snippet Row -->

                    <!-- Facebook Fans Row -->
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Facebook Fans Table  -->
                        <table align="center" style="padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HupyandAbraham/">
                                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/e6mYUw/18000fans_tight.jpg" alt="18000fans" style="width: 85%; height: auto;">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End of Facebook Fans Table -->
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- End of Facebook Fans Row -->

                        <!-- Social Links Row -->
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Social Links Table -->
                            <table align="center" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0">
                                <tr align="center">
                                    <td align="center">                                     
                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/HupyandAbraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #1DA1F2);" alt="Twitter link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-twitter-96.png">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/hupyandabrahamSC" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #ff0000);" alt="YouTube link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-youtube-96.png">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="http://instagram.com/hupyandabraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #C32AA3);" alt="Instagram link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-instagram-96.png">
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr align="center">
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/hupyandabraham/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #BD081C);" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-pinterest-96.png">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hupy-&-abraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #007BB5);" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-linkedin-96.png">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/+HupyandAbrahamSC" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #DB4437);" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-googleplus-96.png">
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- End of Social Links Table -->
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End Social Links Row -->

            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                <!-- End of white background table -->


    </BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the code snippet instead of posting screenshots of the code. Do you expect us to type the entire thing?

Comment: And why are you making seperate tables for the 5 hyperlinks?? You just need 1 <table> with 1 <tr> and 5<td>

Comment: I tried not having separate tables for the links but then it didn't render the padding in Outlook 2010. But it did on web browsers.

It seems to me that tables are allowed to have padding, but web links aren't. In Outlook 2010's world..

Comment: Try this <table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td style="display:flex;">

Comment: Works on a web browser, but not in Outlook. I've read that Outlook 2010 doesn't support Flex at all.

I tried it with and without the children tables. It centers but then I get no spacing between the links.

End up solving one problem and creating another. All because Outlook won't render padding on a link, I guess.

Comment: Try adding width (width around 20%) to the sub-tables and display:block.

Comment: one second :) What client are you using?

Comment: I am wanting to change a few things in your code. If you will allow me a moment I want to share something with you.

Comment: Pretty much everything works in most email clients. But Outlook 2010 is where all of those distorted images are from.

Comment: @scoopzilla I'm all for it!

Comment: This might be helpful.. It's a reference of what CSS attributes are supported by which email clients.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @addison0043 definitely it is helpful. But really, Outlook is  total crapshoot, and you have some things in your code that will break everywhere :)

Comment: @scoopzilla Any specifics on what else I have that will break everywhere? I know certain CSS things don't work in archaic email clients.

My main concern is that the overall layout/table structure stays fairly consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is a revised HTML email template.

First - you have to do a few things. Outlook is super secondary, but unfortunately people still use it. It's horrible.

So you account for that in quite a few ways - in the code and within the header. Luckily your email isn't TOO tricky, so there wasn't any real call for `!mso` in the body of the email.

Secondly - try to make your emails ALSO responsive. Remember that 75% of ALL email is read on a phone. Your email looked like a bit of a mashup. Not in a bad way.

The header links were lining all straight down on Outlook because you had EACH ONE in it's own table. Outlook interpreted that to be tables (obviously) and made each one 100% of the email width. If you place the links inside a table and then each one inside a `<td>` you will get better results.

lastly, there are some interesting shading things going on your email that may or may NOT work in all email clients. I left them but I'd be surprised if they did.

I'd say that you can probably take this code and place it into almost any ESP and it should work. You have to always be mindful of who you are coding emails for, and keep that in mind when it comes to how you design.

Good luck! There's lots more so if you have a question, go ahead and ask.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<title>Royal Caribbean - Advantage Program</title>
<style type="text/css">
  a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: inherit !important;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      font-weight: inherit !important;
      line-height: inherit !important;
  }
  u + #body a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
  }
  #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  body{
   width:100% !important;
   min-width:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  v*{
      behavior:url(#default#VML);
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  td{
   border-collapse: separate !important;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
  a img{
   border:none;
  }
  a {
   text-decoration:none !important;
  }
  img{
   display:block;
   outline:none;
   text-decoration:none;
   border:none; 
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  table{
   border-spacing:0;
   border-collapse:separate;
   mso-table-lspace:0pt;
   mso-table-rspace:0pt;
  }
  table[class=full] {
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
  }
 div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
  p{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   font-size:100%;
   line-height:1.4em;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   font-size:100%;
   line-height:1.4em;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  #wrappertable{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:100% !important;
   line-height:100% !important;
  }
  br[class=show]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }
 @media screen and (max-width:600px){
  table{
   width:100% !important;
  }
  table[class=content]{
   width:95% !important;
  }
  td[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px !important;
   font-size: 0px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   mso-hide: all !important;
   width: 0 !important;
  }
  td[class=fullwidth]{
   width:100% !important;
   float:left !important;
  }
  /*replace image with mobile version*/
  td#pic1 img{
   content:url("") !important;
  }
  /*repeat ID as necessary*/
  img[class=fullwidth]{
   width:100% !important;
   height:auto !important;
  }
  img[class=threequarters]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 75% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=twothirds]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 66.6666% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=halfwidth]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 50% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=onethird]{
   width: 33.3333% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
   padding-top: 5px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  img[class=quarterwidth]{
   width: 25% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
   padding-top: 5px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  img[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px !important;
   font-size: 0px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   mso-hide: all !important;
   width: 0 !important;
  }
  div[class=fullwidth]{
   max-width: 95% !important;
  }
  p,h1,h2[class=centered]{
   text-align: center !important;
  }
  br[class=show]{
  display: inline !important;
  }
  br[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }
  span[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }

 }
</style>
</head>

<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" offset="0" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="padding: 0 !important; margin:0 !important;">
 <center>
 <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="wrappertable">
     <tr>
         <td align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="620" bgcolor="#f9f9f9" style="box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);">
     <tr>
                     <td width="618" align="center">
      <!--THIS IS THE CONTENT TABLE-->
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">
       <tr>
        <td align="center">
         <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 20px"><i>We have collected <strong>MORE THAN $1 BILLION</strong> for thousands of clients.</i></p>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <!--use empty rows for spacing-->
       <tr><td height="20" style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nai2NG/logo_tight.jpg" alt="Voted Best, Rated Vest" width="580" height="150" class="fullwidth"/>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" height="40" style="line-height: 40px;">
         <hr align="center" width="80%" size="1" noshade="noshade"/>
        </td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" width="95%">
          <tr>
           <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/aboutus.cfm"><strong>About</strong></a>
           </td>
           <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px;text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/practice_areas/"><strong>Practice Areas</strong></a>
           </td>
           <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/library/"><strong>Legal Info</strong></a>
           </td>
           <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/case-results.cfm"><strong>Results</strong></a>
           </td>
           <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(165,42,42,.7);" href="https://www.hupy.com/contact.cfm"><strong>Contacts</strong></a>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td height="20" style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" width="95%">
          <tr>
           <td align="center">
            <h2 style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 25px; text-align:left; line-height: 32px;">CASE RESULT: $1.5 Million for Rider Struck by Inattentive Driver</h2>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td height="10" style="line-height: 10px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="center">
            <a href="https://www.hupy.com/case_results/-1-5-million-for-rider-struck-by-inattentive-driver.cfm" target="blank"> 
                                          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eNfVbb/1_5mill.jpg" alt="$1.5 Million" width="580" height="325" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(165,42,42,.7)" class="fullwidth">
                                       </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td height="10" style="line-height: 10px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr>
           <td align="left">
            <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; text-align:left;">In July 2017, our client and his wife were on a casual motorcycle ride in Waukesha County when the driver of a minivan failed to see their motorcycle and turned left in front of them. A terrible crash occurred and both occupants of the motorcycle were ejected. Find out what happened when Hupy and Abraham fought the insurance company to get a $1.5 million settlement.</p>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td height="20" style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HupyandAbraham/">
                                 <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/e6mYUw/18000fans_tight.jpg" alt="18000fans" width="500" height="183" class="fullwidth">
                              </a>
                          </td>
                         </tr>
       <tr><td height="20" style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center">
         <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="center">                                     
                                          <a href="https://twitter.com/HupyandAbraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                              <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #1DA1F2); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Twitter link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-twitter-96.png">
                                          </a>
                                      </td>
           <td align="center">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/hupyandabrahamSC" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                             <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #ff0000); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="YouTube link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-youtube-96.png">
                                          </a>
           </td>
           <td align="center">
             <a href="http://instagram.com/hupyandabraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                             <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #C32AA3); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Instagram link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-instagram-96.png">
                                           </a>
           </td>
                                  </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="3" height="20" style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="center">
                                          <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/hupyandabraham/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                              <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #BD081C); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-pinterest-96.png">
                                          </a>
                                      </td>
           <td align="center">
             <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hupy-&-abraham" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                              <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #007BB5); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-linkedin-96.png">
                                          </a>
           </td>
           <td align="center">
             <a href="https://plus.google.com/+HupyandAbrahamSC" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                              <img style="filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #DB4437); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Pinterest link" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-dark-googleplus-96.png">
                                          </a>
           </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @scoopzilla.

The reason I did them all in separate tables is so it could be more responsive. Works beautifully on a real rendering engine lol. That's why I didn't want to put each one in a <td>.

And yea, none of those shadows will work on Outlook but they show up in more modern clients and it's no harm if a particular client doesn't support them.

I'll be sure to give this a try when I get back to the office. Thanks again!

Comment: @addison0043 you can make them responsive and not put them into tables.

Answer (score 0):

To make a table responsive, just add a media querie like that (direct child selector doesn't affect tables inside this table) :

### Code

```
<table class="responsive-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### The media queries :

```
<style>

    @media all and ( max-width: 600px ) {
        .responsive-table, .responsive-table > tbody, .responsive-table > tbody > tr, .responsive-table > tbody > tr > td {
            display: block !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

You can ajust for your needs